# How to develop C programmes without an IDE in Windows?

Tags: c, ide

I want to have a deeper understanding of how C programmes are run.

But IDEs stops us from doing that.

So is it possible that I manually set up the environment and write code in text editors, and finally run it in a prompt?

If the answer is yes, how?

Comment: C programs are run the way every other program is run, navigate to the directory where the IDE created the binary and double-click the executable or open a command window and type in the path to the executable.  Or is it the process of compilation that you're interested in?

Comment: I'm kind of confused. What does the compilation process have to do with understanding how a program is run? Afterall you can always run the compiled programs outside the ide (e.g. from cmd). If you want to know how it is run you might want to look at the assembler (possibly inside a debugger for better understanding) 
 and/or the executable format depending on what you want to know. If you just want to know howto compile outside an IDE it bears the question for what reasons that would be necessary since (even basic) IDEs are much nicer for that purpose.

Comment: I think following the execution of the program through a debugger would give more meaning of how a program is 'run'.

Comment: As Chris has pointed out above, you will spend a lot of time in a debugger when you are trying to understand how a program is 'run'. A good IDE can actually help. What does *not* help is having some 'wizards' write your code for you. If you are writing all the code, the I don't think an IDE will impact your actual understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have said, install [MinGW](http://tdragon.net/recentgcc/) (I'm assuming you are using Windows) and put its bin directory on your path. Open a command line windows, and create a  file with a text editor, such as notepad - call it foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf( "hello world\n" );
  return 0;
}
```

Then, use the gcc compiler to compile it, creating an executable called foo.exe:

```
> gcc foo.c -o foo.exe
```

lastly, run foo.exe from the command line:

```
> foo.exe
hello world
```

Comment: If he has an IDE installed that can build C programs, then he already has a compiler installed. Why go to the trouble of installing another?

Comment: Nowhere in his question does he say he has an IDE installed.

Comment: That's pretty much what I want!BTW,is it possible to add additional 3rd party libraries to MinGW?

Comment: @Unknown - Yes, of course - libraries are just libraries, it doesn't make any difference where they come from.

Comment: How?I see lots of *.o and *.a under MinGW\lib

Comment: The .a files are libraries. However, you shouldn't really be adding your own libraries there, and this is really not germane to your original question.

Comment: OK,let me open another question:)

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why an IDE should prevent understanding how a C *program* works. An IDE usually abstracts the *building* process, i.e. it creates build rules for you, runs the program and the debugger. This does not have any effect on the way the program itself works, it's just more "user friendly" (depending on how you define "user friendly").

You can always build programs without the help of an IDE. You can even use Microsofts Visual Studio from the command line, and you won't see the GUI at all. Similar for XCode on Mac OS X.

If you want to build a program without using any IDE, you basically write the source code the same way you do with IDE. You can even use the IDE as editor. Afterwards, you need to compile your program. IDEs usually have functionality that makes writing the source code easier like automatic completion of structure elements, basic syntax checking and the like. If the program consists of only one single source file this is usually rather trivial. If you have more than one source file (which should be true for almost everything other than the usual "Hello World" example) you can still do that manually. However, this is a tedious and error prone process. In the Unix world, `make` is the tool of choice to automate this. You can use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) to get such an environment on Windows. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.org) is another alternative here. You could, however, also use `nmake` out of MSVC and write the input for that manually (never did that myself) -- it's basically the same a `Makefile` is for `make`.

Creating a `Makefile` can be non-trivial. There are several generators to make that easier. That's basically the same IDEs do by abstracting the build process. Examples for `Makefile` generators are the [autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) (sometimes also known as "GNU build system") and [cmake](http://www.cmake.org).

Building programs from the command line also does not have any effect about the program having a GUI or not. You can (assuming Windows again) run any `.exe` file from the command line. If it's a GUI application the GUI will show up, if it's a console application it will run in the console window.

Answer (score 2):

Of course! There are a bunch of C compilers available for Windows, a few one to get you going:

- Visual Studio has an express edition which is free and comes with a compiler
- [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) is the Gnu C Compiler ready-to-run for windows
- There are plenty of others, but the ones above should be .. enough for now

As for a text editor, you might want to choose one that comes with C-syntax highlighting, like [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) or some other text editor. Mastering an editor is by the way really useful, regardless of what your language is.

Comment: IIRC, the MS C++ compiler is free to download.

Comment: Right, but you don't need visual studio to use the C/C++ compiler.

Comment: @Alan: but afaik you can only get the compiler as part of the VS package - I don't think MS offers a stand-alone version...

Comment: @Christoph: Nothing stops you from using VC++ from the command line.  The build log from and IDE build even shows you what command-line was issued for each build step.

Comment: @Christoph The free "Windows SDK" from microsoft includes the 32 and 64 bit c/c++ compilers, you don't need VS of any form to use them

Answer (score 2):

Download [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and make sure to install [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), the GNU C compiler.

You can write your C programs in a text editor, compile them with GCC, and then execute them.

Comment: You can't really recommend the Cygwin behemoth just to allow command line builds.  That really is a sledgehammer to crack a nut - it has a place for porting Linux code to Windows but is otherwise ill-advised to use it for native Win32 development.  *All* compilers are command line tools whether driven from an IDE or not.

Comment: Clifford's right. The question was how to do it *without* an IDE. ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean. You want to write C programs in a text editor an then, compile??
Ofcourse, you CAN do that:

```
1- Write a C code
2- Get a compiler such as gcc (there is a windows version)
3- Compile it
4- Run it from console
```

But, I am not sure if that is what you want to know.

Comment: Can you be more specific about compile and run c code without IDE?

Comment: djgpp is a windows C compiler that could be used as well

Comment: @Tom: DJGPP is not a Windows compiler; it is a DOS compiler with a 32bit DOS-extender. See: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq3_6.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You'll need something like [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) compilers set to compile your application (or you could use the IDE-provided compiler).
Then just use CMD and execute appropriate compile commands.

Actually, every IDE provides just more easier way to do the same compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile programs for Windows (if that's what he meant) from the command line using all the available tools in the Windows SDK (formerly called the Platform SDK, I believe) which is free to download from Microsoft. I think it has all the same tools Visual Studio has if not most of them.

Comment: Upvoting this as most of the other comments seem to be suggesting gcc based compilers, which are fine, but it's just as possible to get the microsoft ones, and most examples etc. for the windows platform is targetted at those so it's probably easier in many ways

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in how large projects are organised, you could try downloading the source code for something like [Apache httpd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) or [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). These are both in C.  On Linux/Mac you can compile them from the command-line using a few simple commands (see the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how the build works, most if not all IDE's create a build log which shows the actual command lines issued to invoke the compiler/linker etc.  Nothing prevents you from issuing these commands directly on the command line.

What an IDE typically also does for you is dependency management; this is difficult to maintain manually, and best left to the IDE for large projects.

You do not need to download and install any specific compiler or toolchain as some have suggested; the one you have with your current IDE will be sufficient.  For example if you have VC++2008 (or 2008 Express), the command line tools are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple step that would make you to compile and run c program without IDE

1 - install the TCC (Turbo C compiler)

2- open Notepad and write C code

3 - save as a.c in C:\TC\BIN

4 - then open CMD

5 - compile c code by "tcc a.c"

6 - finally run "a.exe"

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to install the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) compiler and set path to the gcc executable and you're ready to go. Then you can write C code in editor and compile it in command line just like you would on Linux.

Comment: Can you give a demo on compiling and run ?