# How to add 3rd party libraries to MinGW?

Tags: mingw

I've just set up MinGW environment following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985267/how-to-develop-c-programmes-without-an-ide-in-windows/1985328#1985328)

But how to add 3rd party libraries to it?

Comment: https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Using-packages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A library consists of two main components - the C header files and the compiled object code archive. GCC has a bewildering array of ways of specifying these things, but let's say you are using a library `foo.a` which lives in the relative directory path `foo/lib`, and a header `foo.h` which lives in `foo/inc`. Your own C code lives in `main.c` and looks like this:

```
#include "foo.h"
int main() {
  return FooFunc();    // call function in foo.a
}
```

To compile this, you could use the command line:

```
gcc main.c -I foo/inc foo/lib/foo.a -o main.exe
```

the -I flag adds to the path searched for headers. You can also add to the lib path, but then things start to get complicated :-)

Comment: +1,it's helpful!But can you make it more general?Say if I want to include 2 libraries from two different directories.BTW,seems not every library consists of *.h and *.a,at least I see only*.a and *.o under MinGW/lib?

Comment: To specify more include paths, use more -I flags, to specify more libraries, specify them on the command line. At the end of the day, SO is not a tutorial site - read the GCC manual and posibly a book, such as http://www.network-theory.co.uk/gcc/intro.

Answer (score 6):

No different from any other system using `gcc`

- get the sources
- untar
- run configure -- this may require a tweak or two
- make
- make install

and now use your new library with proper `-Lfoo/bar -lfoobar` switches.

I recommend the [MSys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) system around [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) in order to do all this.

Comment: Oh,I forgot to mention that I'm using windows XP,can you be more specific about the details?

Comment: You need a book (or web tutorial) about code development with Unix tools.  There is nothing that specific to Windows XP here --- apart from the fact that you are trying to learn a workflow that is not common on Windows.  You are doing the right thing here, but you more or less need to know how it works on Linux/Unix to infer how it is done on XP.  Just find a decent tutorial somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

I just went through figuring this out myself. I strongly recommend reading the [linking howtos](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO) on the MinGW webpage. Read them carefully as there is quite a lot to take in. They are quite thorough though so it's well worth your time.

There are essentially two ways of doing things. First, you can just regard MinGW as a compiler, because that's what it is, and invoke it from cmd.exe (the command prompt) or an IDE. The other way to do it is to use MSYS which is basically a Unix style shell that you can run on Windows to use Unix style build tools like configure and make.

For either of these you really have to read the howto I linked above to understand how dependency paths are being searched. I hesitate to explain it here as it is already explained in the howtos and duplicating that information is not a good idea. If you have specific questions after reading them I'd be happy to offer more help.

Answer (score 1):

As this has taken me several hours of research on SO to get this 3rd party  run under MinGW, a clear example might help other people who are as new to the topic as me. The question was how to add the 3rd party libraries, and the answer is: you better do not really add them, you just use them as arguments (as already stated by @anon).
I refer to @kjoppy's link recommendation. From http://mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO, at the bottom:

> As a variation on option (2), create a separate directory hierarchy,
>   for each and every individual external library package to be locally
>   installed; this mitigates all of the disadvantages of option (1), and
>   the package intermixing of option (2), but it incurs an alternative
>   penalty:-- As with option (2), appropriate "-I DIR" and "-L DIR"
>   options must be added to each GCC invocation; however, whereas option
>   (2) requires only one additional path of each type, this option
>   requires an additional one of each type, for each and every external
>   library to be deployed. (While this may still be achieved by
>   appropriate customisation of the GCC Specs File, or by appropriately
>   specifying the CPATH and related environment variables, the additional
>   complexity, and maintenance overhead, may be considered unacceptable
>   to many users).

Summing up, they say that the options of GCC Specs File or CPATH as "real 3rd party lib integration" are too much of additional maintenance overhead for the "normal" user, and that we should rather invoke like in the following example:

hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I include mysql.h using a mariadb connector, where the include and the lib is saved separately from gcc defaults. This can be invoked from the commandline (I is include, L is library, the space after these letters is optional)

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -I "C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\include" -L "C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\lib\\" -lmariadbclient
```

If you instead want to run a build task in VS Code, I recommend using the extension
C/C++ Compile Run (extension id: danielpinto8zz6.c-cpp-compile-run)
by pressing F7 and then entering only the arguments:

```
-I "C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\include" -L "C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\lib\\" -lmariadbclient
```

while the c_cpp_properties.json must look like:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This is repeating some answers from here or other similar questions, but they have not helped me enough to get this really started quickly, that is why I post a new answer.