# C++ cannot find SQLite3

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite with c++ on windows. My code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

which returns the error message

```
C:\sqlite: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

There have been several other stackoverflow questions on this but they were all solved by changing `#include <sqlite3.h>` to `#include "sqlite3.h"` or `#include <full_path_to_sqlite3>`, none of which work

One was also solved by including `-lsqlite3` when compiling, but this returns

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

which is odd to me because `sqlite3` works just fine for me normally in cmd

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linking problem basically.

Example solutions:

- Make sure the compiler actually sees the sqlite includes
- If you haven't already, add the library headers folder to the Additional 
  include directories
- Etc.

Just go step by step and make sure everything is in place.

Comment: Can you expand on your second point? I have this in a folder with sqlite.c and sqlite.h, and ive changed line 2 to `#include "sqlite3.h"` and now it has an undefined reference to sqlite3_open.

Comment: Stack Overflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537377/add-extra-include-lib-paths-to-mingw  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985764/how-to-add-3rd-party-libraries-to-mingw  
  
Official MinGW website:  
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW    
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/includepathhowto